# Extract the table from website after click a button failure

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, extract

below is my code to extract the table from website after click a button but failure(refer picture). Hope all who know can help me solve this problem. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/")

button = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[29]/div[2]/input')
button.click()

# Wait for the table to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table")))


# Extract the table data using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
table = soup.find(class="table-responsive")

# Extract the header row and all other rows
header = [th.text.strip() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]
data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")] for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]]

# Create a pandas dataframe from the header and data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)


# Save the dataframe to an Excel file
df.to_excel("table.xlsx", index=False)

# Wait for 10 additional seconds
time.sleep(10)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

this is my first time post question here. Hope anyone who know the problem and solution can help me, Thanks all.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bRzl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `selenium` simply use the api (check browser dev tools on xhr tab) to get the HTML and use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to parse the table - You need `requests` in this case cause they check for `user-agent` in the `headers`.

##### Exanmple

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.read_html(
    requests.get(
        'https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/screener/quote_results', 
        headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
    ).text
)[0]
```

##### Output

|  | Name | Code | Category | Price | Change% | 52week | Volume | EPS | DPS | NTA | PE | DY | ROE | PTBV | MCap.(M) | Indicators | Unnamed: 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | TOPBLDS [s] | 5268 | Construction, Main Market | 0.02 | 0% | 0.010-0.050 | 0 | 21.3 | 0 | 0.001 | 0.09 | 0 | 21302.3 | 20 | 14.12 | QoQ YoY RYoY | nan |
| 1 | PGB [s] | 0091 | Energy, Main Market | 0.2 | -2.4% | 0.080-1.000 | 1190 | 84.43 | 0 | 0.129 | 0.24 | 0 | 652.47 | 1.55 | 120.87 | QoQ YoY | nan |
| 2 | EATECH [s] | 5259 | Transportation & Logistics, Main Market | 0.34 | 1.5% | 0.025-0.365 | 228712 | 19.49 | 0 | 0.03 | 1.74 | 0 | 649.7 | 11.33 | 180.37 | YoY | nan |
| 3 | TECHNAX [s] | 2739 | Energy, Main Market | 0.03 | 20% | 0.000-0.000 | 11037 | 11.07 | 0 | 0.044 | 0.27 | 0 | 251.5 | 0.68 | 66.44 | QoQ YoY RQoQ RYoY | nan |
| 4 | CARLSBG | 2836 | Consumer Products & Services, Main Market | 24.1 | -0.4% | 19.320-24.300 | 1802 | 107.39 | 63 | 0.49 | 22.44 | 2.61 | 219.16 | 49.18 | 7368.53 | QoQ YoY RQoQ RYoY | nan |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1050 | GPP [s] | 03029 | Industrial Products & Services, Leap Market | 0.295 | 0% | 0.295-0.295 | 0 | -9.84 | 0 | 0.02 | -3 | 0 | -492.14 | 14.75 | 45.76 | RQoQ | nan |
| 1051 | DIGISTA | 0029 | Technology, Main Market | 0.095 | 0% | 0.060-0.195 | 18082 | -1.14 | 0 | 0.002 | -8.34 | 0 | -670.35 | 55.88 | 43.11 | YoY RYoY RTopQ | nan |
| 1052 | MCOM [s] | 03022 | Technology, Leap Market | 0.2 | 0% | 0.050-0.200 | 0 | -7.31 | 0 | 0.01 | -2.74 | 0 | -745.44 | 20.41 | 37.71 | nan | nan |
| 1053 | SAPNRG [s] | 5218 | Energy, Main Market | 0.045 | -10% | 0.030-0.100 | 1201122 | -40.76 | 0 | 0.02 | -0.11 | 0 | -2038 | 2.25 | 719.06 | QoQ RConQ | nan |
| 1054 | KANGER [s] | 0170 | Consumer Products & Services, Ace Market | 0.04 | -11.1% | 0.030-0.300 | 278584 | -18.29 | 0 | 0.005 | -0.22 | 0 | -3732.31 | 8.16 | 25.99 | QoQ YoY | nan |